# Colorbar in scale_fill_viridis doesn't include minimum breakpoint

Tags: ggplot2, legend, colorbar

I have a dataframe, sulfide, that looks something like this:

```
sulfide <- data.frame(SiteName = c("Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2"), Activity = c("High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low"), Depth = c("Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep"), value = c(0.02, 0.02, 12.3, 8.6, 7.9, 9.7, 0.02, 0.02, NA, 8.6, 0.02, 1.0))
```

I'm trying to create a plot that shows sulfide concentrations at each of several locations, while also showing trends. My code and plot are here:

```
minimum <- 0.02

ggSulfide <- ggplot(sulfide, aes(x = Activity, y = Depth, fill = value)) + facet_grid(cols = vars(SiteName))
ggSulfide <- ggSulfide + geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1) + coord_equal()

ggSulfide <- ggSulfide + scale_fill_viridis(name = "Concentration\n(mM)", trans = "log", breaks = c(minimum, 0.2, 2, 10), labels = c(minimum, 0.2, 2, 10), limits = c(minimum, max(sulfide$value, na.rm = TRUE)), na.value = "white")

ggSulfide <- ggSulfide + geom_text(aes(label = value), size = geom.text.size)

ggSulfide
```

[Problematic 0.02 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1aIb.png)

Despite specifying breaks, labels, and plot limits, the color bar of this plot is still not displaying my desired minimum value (0.02). This is the detection limit of my assay, so I don't want to toggle it up or down.

However, when I try toggling "minimum" to 0.01, for example, the color bar does display the minimum. Does anyone understand why? Or how I can fix my original color bar?

[0.01 plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCcza.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the `trans = "log"` argument. Is that argument vital to your plot? Removing it will readjust your colorbar, but this will lead to overlapping legend titles. Below is an adjusted plot where all values (including 0.02) are eligible.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
sulfide <- data.frame(SiteName = c("Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", "Site1", 
                                   "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2", "Site2"), 
                      Activity = c("High", "High", "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
                                   "Medium", "Medium", "Low", "Low"), 
                      Depth = c("Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", 
                                "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep", "Shallow", "Deep"), 
                      value = c(0.02, 0.02, 12.3, 8.6, 7.9, 9.7, 0.02, 0.02, NA, 8.6, 0.02, 1.0))

ggSulfide <- ggplot(sulfide, aes(x = Activity, y = Depth, fill = value)) + 
  facet_grid(cols = vars(SiteName)) + 
  geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_viridis(name = "Concentration\n(mM)", 
                     breaks = c(0.02, 2, 6, 10),
                     na.value = "white") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = value), size = 4)

ggSulfide
```

[image]